# can't get current user data in user profile

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, user-profile

I am developing a mobile App where I am currently facing problem on user profile page. Actually i want the current user's detail from login page to display in the user profile page. But unfortunately it only display the data of first user. I need a user profile page to print the information of that user and I am struggling with it. This application login with phone Number.

Please try to help me with this and let me know if you need more information.

I have entered the coding that I have done.

UserProfile.java:

```
public class UserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextInputLayout UfullName, Uusername, Upassword, Uemail, UpNumber, Udate, Ugender;
    TextView Vname;
  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
        
        UfullName = findViewById(R.id.Update_Fname);
        Uusername = findViewById(R.id.Update_Uname);
        Upassword = findViewById(R.id.Update_password);
        Uemail = findViewById(R.id.Update_email);
        UpNumber = findViewById(R.id.Update_Pnumber);
        Ugender = findViewById(R.id.Update_gender);
        Udate = findViewById(R.id.Update_DoB);
        Vname = findViewById(R.id.ViewDName);
       
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
       
        Query usersRef = rootRef.child("donor");
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    
                    String VfullName = ds.child("fullName").getValue(String.class);
                    String fullName = ds.child("fullName").getValue(String.class);
                    String username = ds.child("username").getValue(String.class);
                    String password = ds.child("password").getValue(String.class);
                    String email = ds.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                    String phoneNo = ds.child("phoneNo").getValue(String.class);
                    String gender = ds.child("gender").getValue(String.class);
                    String date = ds.child("date").getValue(String.class);

                    Vname.setText(VfullName);
                    UfullName.getEditText().setText(fullName);
                    Uusername.getEditText().setText(username);
                    Upassword.getEditText().setText(password);
                    Uemail.getEditText().setText(email);
                    UpNumber.getEditText().setText(phoneNo);
                    Ugender.getEditText().setText(gender);
                    Udate.getEditText().setText(date);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        };
        usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the data you have in `donor` in the database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.